# Within an R data.table can you add multiple columns using conditional statements?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to add multiple columns to a data.table depending on the values in other columns, in one function, e.g.

```
d.f <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,1))
d.t <- data.table (d.f)

g <- function(x,y){
  if (y>x)
     return (list(1,2))
   else 
return (list(2,1))
}
 d.t[,c('x','y'):=g(a,b)]
```

But this errors out, and using ifelse doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Perhaps `d.t[, c('x', 'y') := g(a,b), by=1:nrow(d.t)][]`

Comment: look at the output of your function `g(d.t$a, d.t$b)`

Comment: akrun, that works, if you add it as a comment I'll flag it correct

Comment: eddi, it warnings out, but if I use ifelse it silently gives the wrong result

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ifelse` instead of `if (...)` `else`. Also the return statement should be a list of length 2, with each list element having the same length as `x` and `y`.

```
g <- function(x,y){
  list(ifelse(y>x, 1, 2), 
       ifelse(y>x, 2, 1))
}
```

Comment: This works but unfortunately does not solve the issue as it requires duplicating the ifelse (which is more complicated than in the actual example and nested), which is what I'm trying to avoid.